# Access application version from within QML

Tags: qt, qml

I have defined this macro in my `*.pro` project file:

```
# The application version
VERSION = 6.10.0

# Define the preprocessor macro to get the application version in our application.
DEFINES += APP_VERSION=\\\"$$VERSION\\\"
```

Then I set my application version like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    /*
     * Setting the Application version
     */
    app.setApplicationVersion(APP_VERSION);

    // ...

}
```

Now I want to access the application version inside my QML code which is in a **shared library**. How can I do that? :

```
    ColumnLayout {
        id: versionLayout

        StyledLabel {
            text: qsTr("Version")
            font.weight: Font.Bold
        }
        RowLayout {
            StyledLabel {
                Layout.alignment: Qt.AlignCenter
                text: APP_VERSION // How can I access my macro/version here?
                                  //  QApplication.applicationVersion() is NOT working!
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Inside QML, `Qt.application.version` gives the application version.

Comment: How about other macros?